Question without bounty featured
The question "BB84 - Bits needed to detect Eve's presence" is still listed in the featured tab on the main site even though the bounty expired four days ago (wasn't awarded).
Can somebody please fix this?
Illustration:


I'm seeing this with Chromium.

Scratch that. I do see it. I was confused as to where you were looking. I was thinking of featured questions on the right hand side.

Thanks; there was a bug on the "tag engine" (the backend system that deals with this stuff) that failed to update the "count" of an index when that index was being reduced to zero (it is fine when reducing in general - just the zero case is the problem). This meant it was happily reporting data that it knew wasn't "featured" (or whatevever) any more. Essentially (not the actual code!):
// rebuild a filtered+sorted index...
int matches = workspace.ApplyFilter();
if(matches == 0) {
     // nothing to do
} else {
    workspace.ApplySort();
    index.UpdateCountAndCopyFromWorkspace(matches , workspace);
}

In the zero case, it would never actually mark the index as being empty (the "nothing to do" was wrong - it should still have updated the count). Entirely my fault. A permanent fix for this will deploy today.
